# Apply settings in .dir-locals.el to both c and c++ major modes

Tags: major-mode, directory-local-variables, alists

Is there a way to specify the same settings for `c-mode` and `c++-mode` without repeating the alist?
I have:

```lisp
((c-mode . ((comment-start . "/* ")
            (comment-end . " */")
            (comment-padding . 0))))
```

and would like to avoid:

```lisp
((c-mode . ((comment-start . "/* ")
            (comment-end . " */")
            (comment-padding . 0)))

 (c++-mode . ((comment-start . "/* ")
              (comment-end . " */")
              (comment-padding . 0))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as such (AFAIK).

However, both those modes derive from `prog-mode` which *might* be fine to target for this directory.

```el
((prog-mode . ((comment-start . "/* ")
               (comment-end . " */")
               (comment-padding . 0))))
```

Or you could even use `nil`, which applies to *every* mode (again, *maybe* that's ok in practice).

```el
((nil . ((comment-start . "/* ")
         (comment-end . " */")
         (comment-padding . 0))))
```

Otherwise, I think you just have to live with the duplication.

Unless it's just for you, in which case you might be happy with

```el
((c-mode . ((eval . (my-comment-settings))))
 (c++-mode . ((eval . (my-comment-settings)))))
```

calling some `my-comment-settings` function defined in your init file.

```el
(defun my-comment-settings ()
  "My comment settings."
  (setq-local comment-start "/* ")
  (setq-local comment-end " */")
  (setq-local comment-padding 0))
```